# Change a cookie value of a cookie that already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a cookie called SurveyCookie. Created like so:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("SurveyCookie");
cookie.Values["surveyPage"] = "1";
cookie.Values["surveyId"] = "1";
cookie.Values["surveyTitle"] = "Definietly not an NSA Survey....";
cookie.Values["lastVisit"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Which works great. Now the problem comes when I want to change the value "surveyPage" like so.

The below will create a new cookie which is not what I want.

```
int cookieValue = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["SurveyCookie"]["surveyPage"]) + 1;
Response.Cookies["SurveyCookie"]["surveyPage"] = cookieValue.ToString();
```

Then I tried this code below which doesn't work either. The surveyPage is still 1 when it should be 2.

```
Request.Cookies["SurveyCookie"]["surveyPage"] = cookieValue.ToString();
```

Since neither of the above works what does change the cookies value for surveyPage?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

From [ASP.NET Cookies Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx):

> You cannot directly modify a cookie. Instead, changing a cookie
>   consists of creating a new cookie with new values and then sending the
>   cookie to the browser to overwrite the old version on the client.

You can try this:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["SurveyCookie"];
if (cookie == null)
{
    // no cookie found, create it
    cookie = new HttpCookie("SurveyCookie");
    cookie.Values["surveyPage"] = "1";
    cookie.Values["surveyId"] = "1";
    cookie.Values["surveyTitle"] = "Definietly not an NSA Survey....";
    cookie.Values["lastVisit"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
}
else
{
    // update the cookie values
    int newSurveyPage = int.Parse(cookie.Values["surveyPage"]) + 1;
    cookie.Values["surveyPage"] = newSurveyPage.ToString();
}

// update the expiration timestamp
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);

// overwrite the cookie
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: Cookie received in request can have different properties than cookie previously send to browser. For example when sending cookie with SameSite=Lax then we receive it with SameSite=None. When we change the value and add the same cookie to response then we send to browser also SameSite property changes.

Comment: Nowhere in my C# Razor page can I find the HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookieName"]; . . . . .it just underlines the "HttpCookie" with a red line and no amount of Using statements gives me that class or whatever,

Answer (score 10):

You should always create a new cookie each time you need to modify an existing one , the following works for me :

```
var cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie("SurveyCookie");
cookie.Values["surveyPage"] =  newValue;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1000);
cookie.SameSite = System.Web.SameSiteMode.None;
cookie.Secure = true;
this.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: This was the only thing which worked for me- thanks!

Comment: This is a good answer and the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't work with duplicate cookie names with different domains.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the `Response.SetCookie()` method as this will set update your existing cookie

Comment: _HttpResponse.SetCookie()_ supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. The correct way to update a cookie according to Microsoft's _HttpResponse.SetCookie()_ documentation is _Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);_. Refer to the example at the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.setcookie(v=vs.110).aspx