# VB.NET is creating new cookies instead to update existing ones

Tags: javascript, vb.net, cookies

I have an aspx page (page1.aspx) with this:

```
<body onload="SetCookies();">

<script>
function SetCookies() {
    document.cookie = "year=2012";
    document.cookie = "model=Impala";
}
</script>
```

Then in the page1.aspx.vb I have this:

```
Response.Cookies("year").Value = ""
Response.Cookies("model").Value = ""
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "redirect", "window.parent.location='page2.aspx'", True)
```

Finally in page2.aspx I have:

```
<body onload="ShowCookies();">

<script>
function ShowCookies() {
    var mycookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= mycookies.length; i++)
        aString += i + ' ' + mycookies[i - 1] + "\n";
    console.log(aString);
}
</script>
```

The problem is that I am getting this in console:

```
1 year=2012
2 model=Impala
3 year=
4 model=
```

Instead to update my existing cookies it is creating new cookies with the same name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does [Change a cookie value of a cookie that already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070840/change-a-cookie-value-of-a-cookie-that-already-exists) help? (Even though it is in C#.)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look!